# MySQL in Java - inserting set timestamps - current time inserted instead?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I'm having an issue with inserting some timestamps into my database from java. I'm collecting weather forecasts from an API, and then inserting the values into my database. For the historical values it works completely fine, no errors or issues.

However, when I try and insert the future values, for some of the data it will insert it with the current time and date, rather than the set value. I've tried printing out all the final statements, but there isn't any issue. Can anyone see the problem?

```
String sqlCheck = "select * from weatherforecast where datetime = '"
                    + timestamp + "' and stationID = " + stationID;
            PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCheck);
            ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();
            if (r.next()){
                String query = "update weatherforecast set precipitation = ? and temperature = ? and stationID = ? where datetime = ?";
                  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                  preparedStmt.setDouble   (1, o.getRain());
                  preparedStmt.setDouble(2, o.getTemp());
                  preparedStmt.setInt(3, stationID);
                  preparedStmt.setTimestamp(4, timestamp);
                  preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
            } else {
                p1.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
                p1.setDouble(2, o.getRain());
                p1.setDouble(3, o.getTemp());
                p1.setInt(4, stationID);
                p1.execute();
            }
```

I have also added some thread.sleep(2000) in to see if that fixes the issue, but no luck.
I know that the formatting of the timestamp is correct, as the same code is used for the past data. It is also inserting new data for future dates completely fine:

'5800', '2015-04-02 12:00:00', '0', '9', '25'

'6204', '2015-04-02 12:00:00', '0', '8', '21'

'6356', '2015-04-02 12:00:00', '0', '8', '26'

'6386', '2015-04-02 10:06:19', '0', '11', '1'

'6396', '2015-04-02 10:06:19', '0', '8', '2'

'6422', '2015-04-02 10:06:19', '0', '10', '14'

'6447', '2015-04-02 10:06:19', '0', '6', '16'

The datetime values for the bottom four here are meant to be '2015-04-02 09:00:00'
(The time when inserting the data was 10:06:19)

Thanks in advance..!

EDIT

Here's the declaration of the timestamp value (the way that the API stores the time needed interpreting hence the if statements)

```
else if (o.getTime().equals("2100")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 21:00:00.0");

            }
```

The date part of the observation is stored in the format:

"date": "2015-04-05"

EDIT 2:

```
Timestamp timestamp = null;

            if (o.getTime().equals("300")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 03:00:00.0");

            } else if (o.getTime().equals("0")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 00:00:00.0");

            } else if (o.getTime().equals("600")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 06:00:00.0");

            } else if (o.getTime().equals("900")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 09:00:00.0");

            } else if (o.getTime().equals("1200")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 12:00:00.0");

            } else if (o.getTime().equals("1500")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 15:00:00.0");

            } else if (o.getTime().equals("1800")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 18:00:00.0");

            } else if (o.getTime().equals("2100")) {
                timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(o.getDate() + " 21:00:00.0");

            }
```

Comment: We need to see what `timestamp` is - could you include its declaration/initialisation in the question?

Comment: Is your select query getting prepared properly?

Comment: The fact that the time isn't set to 21:00 in the inserted data implies that the `if` condition may have evaluated to `false`. What are the other conditions in there, what is `o` and how is it retrieved?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the select query is working, as it isn't inserting any duplicate values from previous runs of the code.
I've updated my question again to include the entire loop :)